# How to autorun collectstatic on local django instance?

Tags: python, django, heroku

While developing locally on a side Django project, my workflow is currently this:

1. Make changes.
2. Go to Terminal session with virtual environment. Stop foreman with ctrl+C.
3. Type `python manage.py collectstatic` to move all my static css/js/img files.
4. Restart foreman with `foreman start`.

In an attempt to be more efficient and do a better job of learning, I'm wondering how I can optimize the workflow is it's more like this:

1. Make changes.
2. Run a single command that moves static files and restarts foreman.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bash script that does this bunch of commads for you.

While I have no experience with foreman, you could create a script with content something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo killall foreman
python manage.py collectstatic
foreman start
```

Then add execution rights to it:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And execute everything in one command:

```
./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you absolutely can't get around using foreman for local development, cause otherwise you would not even need to do a collectstatic or manual restart.

Maybe writting a custom management command based on runserver is the way to go for you, as it would already have the check-for-change-and-restart logic in it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py?source=cc